# Parse Json String Without using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I encountered an issue which is I want to get the data from innermost json. Eg, I input **Swimming** then I will get **student_ID : 0001** and **Name : Jack**. Something like this but I don't want to use Newtonsoft or any other dll. My current code is shown below, I able to get data for the outmost which is **Name** and **Birthday** but not embedded. My code and json are below

```
{
   "Name":"Jack",
   "birthday":"11-Jan-2022",
   "embedded":{
      "OtherInfo":[
         {
            "student_ID":"0001",
            "Batch":"2022-02",
            "Hobby":{
               "Sport":"Swimming",
               "Arcade":"Fencing"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

```
    public class Hobby
    {
        public string Sport { get; set; }
        public string Arcade { get; set; }
    }

    public class OtherInfo
    {
        public string student_ID { get; set; }
        public string Batch { get; set; }
        public Hobby Hobby { get; set; }
    }

    public class Embedded
    {
        public List<OtherInfo> OtherInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
        public Embedded embedded { get; set; }
    }
```

```
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(ApiCreateJsonData);
string testtsett = "";
foreach (var item in jsonObj.Name)
{
    testtsett += item.ToString();   
}
Label1.Text = testtsett;
```

Comment: Why would you deliberately make your life harder?

Comment: I wish I can use newtonsoft but I can't :( the project itself does not contain this dll

Comment: What's stopping you from using it? Why can't you just add Newtonsoft's JSON.NET using NuGet?

Comment: My project is IIS project, I cannot build dependancy :((

Comment: `My project is IIS project, I cannot build dependancy :(( ` - that doesn't really make sense...

Comment: I try to add nuget and it doesn't work, nothing prompt

Comment: sorry I just a rookie programmer :(

Comment: I would focus on fixing that rather than trying to work without 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to Tools | NuGet Package Manager | Manage NuGet packages for the solution. Make sure you select "Browse" rather than the default "Installed". Search for JSON.NET and install.

Comment: Hi , i clicked on it and nothing prompt out, I know how to install nuget but this project doesn't work

Comment: You can not access `jsonObj.Embedded` property?

Comment: i can, but inside was empty

Comment: You mean `jsonObj.Embedded.OtherInfo` does not have any item in it?

Comment: yep, I try to do like foreach(var item in jsonObj.Embedded), output was empty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
foreach (var item in jsonObj.embedded.OtherInfo)
{
  testtsett += item.student_ID;
  testtsett += item.Hobby.Arcade;
  testtsett += item.Hobby.Sport;
  testtsett += item.Batch;
}
```

You need to loop over your `List<OtherInfo>` to get your `embedded` values:

Comment: Hi, it showing does not contain a defination for 'Other Info'

Comment: @pikabob There is no space in `OtherInfo`